# Oppus Engine not found error despite having installed packages

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, npm-install, opus

This problem has being getting at me all day and I cannot figure out what is wrong. I have already looked at other tutorials on how to play mp3 files through discord.js and the other pages describing how to get rid of this error. They all just say to install the packages but I have already installed more than the necessary amount of packages including: `discord.js ffmpeg opusscript @discordjs/opus ytdl-core node-opus`. Yet when I run this code below I get the same error every time, `(node:10912) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Couldn't find an Opus engine.` I am really stumped and do not know what to do now. Any help is much appreciated.
Here is my code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);

});

client.on('message', message => {
    var server = client.guilds[message.guild.id];
    var mention = 0;
    console.log(message.content);
    if(message.mentions)
    {
        mention = message.mentions.users.first();
        // console.log(message.author);
    }

  if (message.content === 'testing') {


    message.reply(' test Succesful!');
    // console.log(message.channel.id+" and the guild is: "+ message.guild.id);
    if (message.member.voiceChannel)
    {
        message.member.voiceChannel.join().then(connection => {
            connection.playFile(`C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\Shepard Tone.mp3`)
            console.log("Successfully connected.");
          })
    }
    else
    {
        message.reply(" Make sure you are in a voice channel.")
    }
  }
});
client.login('SUPER SECRET TOKEN');
```

Comment: Try reinstalling npm? Suggesting this based on: https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/872

Comment: I have just tried that but I am still facing the same issue. Any other ideas?